# Python json.loads object_hook=OrderedDict not working

Tags: python, json

I have the following json file:

```
{
  "glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossaryID": "5302",
    "GlossDiv": {
      "title": "S",
      "GlossList": {
        "GlossEntry": {
          "ID": "SGML",
          "SortAs": "SGML",
          "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
          "Acronym": "SGML",
          "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
          "GlossDef": {
            "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
            "GlossSeeAlso": [
              "GML",
              "XML"
            ]
          },
          "GlossSee": "markup"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am reading this json file using following command:

data = json.loads(str,object_hook=OrderedDict)

But, it still doesn't maintain the order of insertion:

```
OrderedDict([
  (u'glossary',
  OrderedDict([
    (u'GlossDiv',
    OrderedDict([
      (u'GlossList',
      OrderedDict([
        (u'GlossEntry',
        OrderedDict([
          (u'GlossDef',
          OrderedDict([
            (u'GlossSeeAlso',
            [
              u'GML',
              u'XML'
            ]),
            (u'para',
            u'A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.')
          ])),
          (u'GlossSee',
          u'markup'),
          (u'Acronym',
          u'SGML'),
          (u'GlossTerm',
          u'Standard Generalized Markup Language'),
          (u'Abbrev',
          u'ISO 8879:1986'),
          (u'SortAs',
          u'SGML'),
          (u'ID',
          u'SGML')
        ]))
      ])),
      (u'title',
      u'S')
    ])),
    (u'GlossaryID',
    u'5302'),
    (u'title',
    u'example glossary')
  ]))
])
```

I am looping through the items in the dictionary and listing out the root element and its elements. I want it in the same order as it is in the json file.

I am looking for structures and arrays in the json and each array or structure will be a different table for me.
So I want the output as:

```
Glossary-
title:example glossary,
GlossaryID:5302

GlossDiv-
title:S

GlossEntry-
ID: SGML,
SortAs: SGML,
GlossTerm: Standard Generalized Markup Language,
Acronym: SGML,
Abbrev: ISO 8879:1986,
GlossSee: markup
```

and so on.
But, because its not maintaining the order I am getting it as:

```
glossary
GlossDiv
GlossList
GlossEntry
GlossDef
GlossSeeAlso
para : A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.
GlossSee : markup
Acronym : SGML
GlossTerm : Standard Generalized Markup Language
Abbrev : ISO 8879:1986
SortAs : SGML
ID : SGML
title : S
GlossaryID : 5302
title : example glossary
```

Comment: can you tell what output you want ?

Comment: I am looking for structures and arrays in the json and each array or structure will be a different table for me.
So I want the output as:
Glossary-
title:example glossary,
GlossaryID:5302,

GlossDiv-
title:S,

GlossEntry-
ID: SGML,
SortAs: SGML,
GlossTerm: Standard Generalized Markup Language,
Acronym: SGML,
Abbrev: ISO 8879:1986,
GlossSee: markup,

and so on.
But, because its not maintaining the order I am getting it as:
glossary,
GlossDiv,
GlossList,
GlossEntry,
GlossDef,
GlossSeeAlso,
para : A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `object_hook` parameter, the decoder will first reconstruct the mapping as a plain dict, then pass that dict to the given hook. This will lose the ordering of the items.

Presumably you're using a version of python before 3.7 (as dicts became ordered by default in 3.7), and if you check the `json` module documentation for your version (eg. [3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.load)), you'll find the answer in the `object_pairs_hook` parameter:

> *object_pairs_hook* is an optional function that will be called with the result of any object literal decoded with an ordered list of pairs. The return value of *object_pairs_hook* will be used instead of the `dict`. This feature can be used to implement custom decoders that rely on the order that the key and value pairs are decoded (for example, `collections.OrderedDict()` will remember the order of insertion). If *object_hook* is also defined, the *object_pairs_hook* takes priority.

Replace `object_hook` with `object_pairs_hook`, and this should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

according to the docs:

> object_hook is an optional function that will be called with the result of any object literal decoded (a dict). The return value of object_hook will be used instead of the dict.

so as you can understand - this transformation happen at the end of the `load` function, meaning that the output will not be "Ordered" since it receives the `dict` from `load` as a whole. `OrderedDict` only keep the order of keys and values entered to the `OrderedDict` after he was declared "Ordered".

so basically the hook works - but no as you expected. :)